# Click function still working for previous class which is already replaced by other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with jQuery click event. When I replace the class of a `div` the click function is still working for the previous class. Here is the code I am working with:

```
$(this).removeClass('edit_agent_val').addClass('edit_agent_val2');
```

The click function is still working for `edit_agent_val` instead of `edit_agent_val2`.

```
// This should not work
$('.edit_agent_val').on('click', function(e) {          
     // some code...
});

// This should work
$('.edit_agent_val2').on('click', function(e) { 
    // some code...
});
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Need to use event delegation as the normal selectors are evaluated only when the handlers are registered any changes done to the event will not affect the added handlers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because the events are attached on load when the element still has the original class. The act of changing a class attribute does not affect any of the events attached to the element.

To achieve what you want you would need to use a delegated event handler, which is attached to a parent element:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_agent_val', function(e) {
     // some code...
});

$(document).on('click', '.edit_agent_val2', function(e) {
    // some code...
});
```

Note that I have only used `document` here as an example. In final working code you should use the closest parent element to both `.edit_agent_val` elements.

Comment: thanks for your help, but there is one more issue i just observed, that as there are 4 more classes with the name 'edit_agent_val2', now when i use delegated event handler, the function is being running four times instead of one. Where i am wrong now? :(

Comment: You'd probably be best to open a new question for that - including the full code you have.

Comment: ok i have opened a new question for this issue, here is the link, i haven't got any solution for this till now, please take a look if you can sort this out for me... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820088/delegated-event-handler-is-working-more-than-once-for-same-class

Answer (score 2):

Use `event delegation` for adding and removing the class dynamically.

If the Dom didn't know the class is removed or not on traversed so use of document or immediate parent selector to traverse it again and check the class is found or not

```
$(document/immediateParent).on('click', '.edit_agent_val' ,function(e){          **// This should not work**
     // some code...
});

$(document/immediateParent).on('click', '.edit_agent_val2', function(e){        **// This should work**
    // some code...
});
```