# Delegated event handler is working more than once for same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having the problem with the delegated event used for click function, I have four images with different id but with same class 'edit_agent_val', when I click on any image the function runs four times instead of once.

Here is the code I have used:
Be sure to take a look at the images I am working with:

```
<img id="treegrid-1" class="edit_agent_val" src="/palodrive/img/addb.svg" data-user="Player" data-name="pessimist">
<img id="treegrid-2" class="edit_agent_val" src="/palodrive/img/addb.svg" data-user="Player" data-name="Naugahyde">
<img id="treegrid-3" class="edit_agent_val" src="/palodrive/img/addb.svg" data-user="Player" data-name="lemma">
<img id="treegrid-4" class="edit_agent_val" src="/palodrive/img/addb.svg" data-user="Player" data-name="rackoz">
```

And here is the function which runs four times instead of once:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $(document).on('click', '.edit_agent_val', function() {    
         alert("sdsdsd");
     });
});
```

Comment: how many times did the code `$(document).on('click', '.edit_agent_val', function() {` executed?

Comment: You code appears correct, so there is something else going on. Can you show your entire page's HTML? Where are you running the code shown?

Comment: Works fine for me!..Probably you should create fiddle and share where this problem reproduces..

Comment: where is that code placed.... it should be executed on dom ready.. not in another event handler or function which will be callled multiple times

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar: That is the least helpful comment I have seen all day! :)

Comment: can you add a alert/console.log just before `$(document).on('click', '.edit_agent_val', function() {` and see how many times it is geting called

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/uv9c7916/1/ - the same code (with different images). Could you click a couple of times on the images and check what you get in your browser's Console?

Comment: wooh! yes it seems to work well, i still don't know where i am going wrong in my case, anyways, my problem has been solved by using event.preventDefault(); but still, thanks so much for your help and such a good example.... +1 for this :)